# Perl one-liner to match contractions such as I'd and can't

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing Perl code to match English contractions such as `I'd` and `can't`
I could solve the problem by transforming my code into a short script, but I would like to know if this can be solved with a one-liner.

My sample text is:

```
I'd like to match only contractions using a Perl one liner but it's tricky
```

The output should be:

```
I'd
it's
```

I can't put a bare single-quote inside of the regex, since that would prematurely end the perl expression:

```
perl -lane 'for (@F) {print if /^[a-zA-z]+'[a-zA-Z]+$/}' file
Illegal variable name.
```

Escaping the single-quote with a backslash isn't working:

```
perl -lane 'for (@F) {print if /^[a-zA-z]+\'[a-zA-Z]+$/}' file
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: put the expression in double quotes? `"for (@F) {print if /^[a-zA-z]+'[a-zA-Z]+$/}"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Works in this case, but not a good idea in general, since the shell will expand certain characters inside double quotes in Bourne shell variants.

Comment: You can replace the single-quote in the regex with `\x27`, which is simply its hex representation.

Comment: Thanks.  These both worked:  `perl -lane 'for (@F) {print if /^[a-zA-z]+\047[a-zA-Z]+$/}' file`  and  `perl -lane 'for (@F) {print if /^[a-zA-z]+\x27[a-zA-Z]+$/}' file`

Comment: I didn't understand why a backslash didn't properly escape the quote.  Evidently bash has the rule "a single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash." - http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-quoting.html